# IPhone Dev: setHidesBackButton hides the button but leave it working..!

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button

I don´t know if it was supposing to happen, but when I set:

[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];

or

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

it works, the button is hidden... BUT if I press the area where the button was supposed to be, the "invisible" button works..! This is correct..?

If I really want a invisible and not operable button I will need to set a empty button at leftBarButton..???

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know thats correct behavior. I've had that happen every time I've hidden the back button.

Try using.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtomItem = nil;
```

Comment: Sorry man, but now is working... I made a Clean All and them I rebuild everything and them worked... Thanks for helping me in this..!